# Access SQL Query Help

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access-2007

***I have a query in which I need to perform using three entities listed below:***

1. LU_AppName
2. SDB_AppHistory
3. SDB_Session

LU_AppName has field APPNAM, SDB_AppHistory has the field STARTTIME which is date/time and also SDB_Session has field DURATION.

I need to run an SQL query to show me Citrix APPLICATIONS which have not been used in the last 6 months.

***At the moment I have the code below.***

```
SELECT dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME, dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY.STARTTIME
FROM dbo_LU_APPNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY ON dbo_LU_APPNAME.PK_APPNAMEID = dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY.FK_APPNAMEID
WHERE (((dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME) Like "* Citrix") AND ((dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY.STARTTIME) Between DateAdd("d",-180, Getdate())))
```

I am a bit confused as I am not very good with SQL

Can anyone please advice, if you require more info please let me know.

Thanks, any help would be greatfull.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're missing 1/2 of the BETWEEN clause...

AND ((dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY.STARTTIME) Between GetDate() AND DateAdd("d",-180, Getdate())

Comment: GETDATE() dont seem to be recognised in ACCESS 2007 SQL View, NOW() seems fine.

Any alternatives

Comment: The Access/Jet/ACE function is Date().

Comment: I assumed that the OP had the correct function, I was just pointing out he was missing the rest of the criteria for BETWEEN....
So it would be:
AND ((dbo_SDB_APPHISTORY.STARTTIME) Between Date() AND Date() - 180)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date() instead of GetDate:

```
DateAdd("d",-180, Date())
```

Date() is quite happy with:

```
Date()-180
```

DateAdd will accept "m", if you wish to consider months:

```
DateAdd("m",-6, Date())
```

Watch out for date formats and locale.